# How to fix error when updating phone number format?

Tags: sql-server

Ok, I am using SQL Server 2016 and I am trying to figure out how to update the phone numbers from the Customers table. Which look like this "1234567890", and when I run this query:

```
USE ProductsDatabase2;

UPDATE Customers
SET PhoneNumber = '(' + SUBSTRING(PhoneNumber, 1, 3) + ') ' +
    SUBSTRING(PhoneNumber, 4, 3) + '-' + SUBSTRING(PhoneNumber, 7, 4)
```

I get this error message:

Msg 8152, Level 16, State 13, Line 3
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.

Here is the Customers table:

[image]

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: the new phone number is wider than the old and wont fit in the column datatype. you would need to increase the max length of that.

Comment: which data type would you recommend? I tried changing the size from nvarchar(10) to nvarchar(50) and higher, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: following your edit not that then. as the length of the string will be 14. any triggers on the table?

Comment: actually I dont think its letting me save the changes to data type.

Comment: ok, for some reason it is not letting me save changes to nvarchar(50). And no I do not have a trigger to the table. Do I have to make one?

Comment: Alter your table via SQL, not the wizard. `alter table Customers alter column PhoneNumber varchar(50)`

Comment: Ok, thanks that solved the problem.